# verilog code containing adders

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

i write the verilog code which contain only adders. In this g,h are 10 bits and r5(main output) is of 11 bits. When i take r5 as 11 bits then i am not getting correct output but when i take r5 as 10 bits then i am getting correct. but (r5=g+h) so its bit should be one more than bits of g,h.
i took input as clk = 1;

```
    s189 = 10'd200;
    s375 = 10'd75;
    s050 = 10'd300;
    s218 = 10'd54;
```

and output should be r5= -16 but it gives output as (01111110000) instead of (11111110000)

```
module out(clk,s189,s375,s050,s218,r5,g,h);
input clk;
input [9:0] s189,s375,s050,s218;
output reg[10:0] r5;
output reg [9:0] g,h;
reg [3:0] countr=4'b0000;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
if (countr==4'b1000)
begin
 g<= s218-s189;
 h<= s375+s050;
 r5<=g+h;
 end
end

always@(posedge clk)
begin
 if (countr==4'b1001)
 countr<=4'b0000;
 else 
 countr<= countr+1;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing unsigned arithmetic, as noted the MSB is 0 not 1 (negative) as expected. You need to declare the inputs, outputs and variables used as signed, for automatic sign extension.

```
module out(
  input clk, 
  input signed [9:0] s189,
  input signed [9:0] s375,
  input signed [9:0] s050,
  input signed [9:0] s218,
  output reg signed [10:0] r5,
  output reg signed [9:0] g,
  output reg signed [9:0] h
);
```

Comment: @user3212932 no problem, be careful with your `g` and `h` as 10 bit + or - 10bit can have an 11 bit result, and these may overflow. `g` and `h` should really be 11 bit and `r5` 12 bit if you want to avoid overflow/underflow conditions.